# Are there any pre-reqs for using Azure AD with ASP.Net MVC on IIS

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, office365, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.Net MVC Web App that has been configured to use Azure AD for authentication. I have configured Azure AD with 2 Reply URLs - one localhost for development and one for production hosting. The site works fine running on my machine on localhost, using IIS Express through Visual Studio. It also runs fine on my machine (and other devs machine's also) when using full blown IIS and the full domain name (mapped locally to my machine through the hosts file). However, if I try to deploy the exact same codebase to a host server (Win 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5 / .Net 4.5) the authentication doesn't work. This is using the exact same URL as works on IIS on my machine.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be preventing my app from running on the server? I have no error messages to go on. After the Azure AD login page I get redirected back to my app where it cycles for a minute or so and just remains a white screen. I have now tried it on 2 separate host servers and got the same result.

Hopefully someone can help, I really need to get this working. Should this just work?

Thanks.

Comment: Any firewall from host to the URLs?

Comment: There was a firewall on my corporate network for the first prod server, but my laptop goes through the same firewall. My latest attempt is on an Azure VM. I've not changed any firewall settings for that server.

Comment: It's tough to give an answer with so little to go on. It should work as you said. You said the login page redirects, so I'm guessing this is where you are getting the authorization code and then using that to retrieve an access token? Can you tell if it's even getting that far?

Comment: The problem appears to be server-related from what I can see. We do now have the same code running on other servers. I'm not sure what the problem was with the original server. Thanks for your help on this matter. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be just with the one server. I got the process working on other servers and an Azure website. I didn't get to the bottom of what the actual root cause was.